# UIView Element Layout Constraints

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm fairly new to iOS development but have reached the point where I want to create my own composite UIView as a custom UIButton. I would like to layout a UILabel and 2x UIImageViews as follows;

[image]

But I would also like to anchor the controls (subviews) in such a way that as the label expands, due to translations say, the view automatically handles the extra real estate. For example;

[image]

Ideally -

- the right hand side UIView is anchored to the right; and remains a fixed width/hight (right aligned).
- the label and bottom image divide the remaining left hand space

  - the label is vertically centered in the top half of the upper remaining space
  - the bottom image remains centered (both vertically and horizontally) in the lower remaining space
- if the label is wider than the bottom image then the view should expand

I'm happy to construct this in pure code if required. I used a XIB in the above images to play with attributes and to visualize my question.

I'm from a C#/XAML background so I would typically use grid layouts with fixed/auto/* columns and rows but I'm guessing I need to use something like NSLayoutConstraints here - unfortunately I don't know where to start or how to search for the solution. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your UIButton

(code not tested)

```
//put the code below in your button's init method    

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UIImageView *bottomImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImageView *rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

// we define our own contraints, 
// we don't want the system to fall-back on UIView's autoresizingMask property (pre-iOS 6)
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
bottomImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
rightImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

//fixed sizes => SET THESE as you want
CGFloat labelHeight, bottomWidth, rightImageWidth;


// 1 - Label constraints :
// labelWidth = 1 *self.width - rightImageWidth
NSLayoutConstraint *labelWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:(- rightImageWidth)];

// label must be at the top :
NSLayoutConstraint *labelTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

//label must be on the left border
NSLayoutConstraint *labelLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

//label must be of 1/2 height

NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:0.5
                                                                constant:0];

[self addSubview:label];
[self addConstraints:@[labelWidth, labelTop, labelLeft, labelHeight]];

//2 - botom view
// width constant
NSLayoutContraint *bottomWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                              multiplier:0
                                                                constant:bottomWidth];

// same height constraint as label
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:0.5
                                                                constant:0];

// sticks at container's bottom (pun intended)
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

//we have height, width, y contraints, just x remains
// NOTE : this one is between bottom view and label
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomCenteredXAsLabel = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:label
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

[self addSubview:bottomImageView];
[self addConstraints:@[bottomWidth, bottomHeight, bottomBottom, bottomCenteredXAsLabel]];

// 3 - last one !
NSLayoutConstraint *rightAligned = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

//right height
NSLayoutConstraint *rightHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

//constant width...
NSLayoutConstraint *rightWidth =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                              multiplier:0
                                                                constant:rightImageWidth];

//width, height, x constraints... 
//we still need one on y, let's say it sticks at the top

NSLayoutConstraint *rightTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightImageView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];

[self addSubview:rightImageView];
[self addConstraints:@[rightAligned, rightHeight, rightWidth, rightTop]];
```

Et voilà !

The method is always the same : you need at least 4 constraints on each view, setting width, height, x, and y (CGRect 4 dimensions).
Think of a constraint as a relation :

```
item1.layoutAttribute1 >= a*item2.layoutAttribute2 + b
```

to translate in this form

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:item1
                             attribute:layoutAttribute1
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                toItem:item2
                             attribute:layoutAttribute2
                            multiplier:a
                              constant:b];
```

Note that using visual format, you might express all that with less code. (but I've not played with it yet).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

I had to make a few changes but it worked great. For others reading this I needed to update `addSubView` to `addSubview`, I needed to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on all the subviews, I needed to change the `self.view` to just `self` as I was subclassing a UIButton and call `[super layoutSubviews]` before and after the above code.

Comment: answer edited! But you should never call `layoutSubviews` directly (I've never needed that) see the method comment (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews). All this code - setting subviews - should be called BEFORE addind this button to a view hierarchy (e.g. :in your button subclass init method)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had overridden layoutSubviews to do this work - so I had to call `[super layoutSubviews]` otherwise an exception thrown stating I needed to make the call! I've moved the code to `init` and I removed the superfluous code.

Comment: Note; I spent a couple of hours trying to resize the parent UIButton to have a width that was sufficient for the UILabel but I still haven't found a solution. I'll revisit tomorrow.