# UIImageView: use all available space via auto layout

Tags: xcode, ios6, autolayout

I'm trying to use Auto Layout to minimize the gap between a `UIImageView` (in green) and a `UICollectionView` (in red). In the simulator (which I assume is showing an iPhone 4-size screen) the two views line up nicely, with only a small gap between:

[image: iPhone 4 simulator image]

However on my actual device, an iPhone 5 with larger screen, there's a big gap:

[image: iPhone 5 actual device image]

How can I specify auto layout constraints so that the `UIImageView` (green box) takes up as much space as available, regardless of screen size, while keeping the `UICollectionView` pinned to the bottom toolbar?

I've tried experimenting with adjusting the constraints, adding pins, etc in XCode without much success. I feel like I'm just flailing around not really understanding how they work, and I have yet to find a good tutorial that explains how do something like "expand to take up as much vertical space as possible".

Comment: I answered to a similar question yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076362/uiview-element-layout-constraints). Basically, right now, your red view seems to have has a **constant** height-constraint, and a **fixed to bottom** y-constraint. While you might want a fixed **H** height for green view, and the red one automatically stretching its height on `totalHeight - H`. Do you already use constraints, or UIView's `autoresizingMask`?

Answer (score 2):

So you need to specify that the gap between the two views is fixed, and that the height of the bottom view is also fixed. In visual format language that would be

```
"V:|[topView]-[bottomView(==150)]|"
```

`V:` means this is a vertical constraint

`|[topView]` means pin the top of `topView` as close to the top edge of the superview as possible.

`-` means that the space between the two views is fixed

`[bottomView(==150)]` means that `bottomView` **must** be 150 pixels

`]|` means that the bottom edge of `bottomView` is pinned to the bottom edge of the superview

You could also add these constraints in Interface Builder by setting a fixed height on the bottom view, and a fixed gap between the top and bottom views

Comment: Not wishing to self publicise, but I wrote a couple of tutorials on using Autolayout on Cocoa, but the principles apply to Cocoa-touch as well: http://comelearncocoawithme.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/laying-out-interfaces-automatically.html

Comment: Here is another tutorial for Cocoa-touch: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Is that RubyMotion ASCII layout? Wish I could use that. Storyboard/IB is maddening. I select a constraint in the Storyboard, and then the detail pane goes completely blank. I can't edit it!

Comment: I believe part of the problem I'm having is that the green box is a UIImageView, and it seems to want a fixed size. I want it to expand to fill the available space, but not sure how to indicate that with a constraint.

Comment: Yeah, there's numerous bugs in XCode related to constraints. The ASCII constraint string is the Autolayout visual format string, you can use it in the code to set constraints. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_the_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Visual_Format_Language